# format multiselect column as url

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Is it possible to format each value in a choice column as URL with JSON formatting?

I have the following values, mostly 2-3.

- RoadmapIds: 84027
- BlogLink: https://oneurl
- ExternalLink: https://anotherurl

I would like to make the 2 URL's clickable. So, I tries this, but this doesn't work. Even if I put some static URL in the `href` attribute.

Is it even possible to create links on item level in a multiselect column?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "__INTERNAL__ in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "txtContent": "[$__INTERNAL__]",
      "attributes": {
        "href": "=replace(@txtContent, 'ExternalLink: ','')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong `elmType` in your JSON. To create links, you have to use the `a` elemType.

For example (with static link):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px",
        "text-decoration": "none"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "href": "https://www.google.com/",
        "target": "_blank"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Similar JSON sample**: [Multi-Choice link](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-choice-link)